# Can "Customer Community Login" make use of ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.* classes and methods?

Tags: community, connect-api

Can "Customer Community Login" license make use of ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.* classes and methods?  If so, is there a profile tweak that needs to be done?  Initial attempts to execute the following ...

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me');
```

...produces the following error....

```
"Insufficient Privileges - You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary."
```

If I run the same page as an internal user, the code executes correctly.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for the help.

Cheers,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make use but first parameter you will need to keep communityId instead of null

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItemsFromFeed(communityId, ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me');
```

You can get logged in user community Id using below code

```
String communityId=Network.getNetworkId();
```

Answer (score 0):

This also applies to getUserBatch.

```
String commId = Network.GetNetworkId();
ConnectApi.BatchResult[] batchResults = ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.getUserBatch(commId, userList);
```

Thanks Mohith!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/37917)

Comment: I added this because when searching for the answer I was looking for regarding Batch results, this did not come up. I assumed by adding this it would. I didn't think re-posting this solution would give credit to the person who came up with it. I suppose if moderators feel the need, this can be removed. Also I can not comment on other people's post yet. Thanks for the feedback, I will be more careful in the future.